# Vue: Setting initial data string with link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, v-for

I have an array of objects as `boxData` in my initial data.  How would I go about making the word "here" a hyperlink that I can use whenever referencing `boxData`?

```
data() {
    return {
        boxData: [
            {
                body: "This is the link here."
            },
            {
                body: "Normal text."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Child component**

```
<div v-for="(box, index) in boxData" class="box">
    <div>
         {{ box.body }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `<a :href="boxData.body">Link</a>`

Comment: Question unclear:  1) Will these objects all be displayed at once?  2) Will they all have the word here?  3) Will they also specify their link URLs?

Comment: @Dan I made an edit to make it clearer.  The word `here` just needs to be a hyperlink in that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the objects with a link would have a property like `url`.  Then, assuming all of the links should say "This is the link here", you could do:

```
<div v-for="(box, index) in boxData" class="box">
  <div>
    <template v-if="box.url">
      This is the link <a :href="box.url">here</a>.
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      {{ box.body }}
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you don't need "This is the link here" in any of the objects.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to put the data into the hyperlink like so:

```
<a :href="boxData.body">Here</a>
```

Much better

```
<router-link :to="boxData.body">Here</router-link>
```